# Add Identity column to AspNetUsers table MVC Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I am new to MVC Core. I am using MS Identity for user accounts.

I have extended the IdentityUser with my own ApplicationUser like this:

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace BeeKeeper.Models
{
    public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        public string LastName { get; set; }

        public string BusinessName { get; set; }

        public string PostalAddress { get; set; }

        [StringLength(20)]
        public string PostalPostcode { get; set; }

        public string ResidentialAddress { get; set; }

        [StringLength(20)]
        public string ResidentialPostcode { get; set; }

        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int User_ID { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I need my MVC Core system to allow there to be an ID column in the AspNetUsers table that is an auto incremented column.

My client currently is using an Excel spreadsheet to register bee keepers. They want to retain the registration numbers of those records in the spreadsheet in this new MVC system. They get the bee keepers to label their bee hives with their registration number, which is a simple integer. So I will need to create new users in the database by importing them into the AspNetUsers table, retaining those registration numbers. And new users will need an auto-incremented registration number to put on their bee hive. Using an int Identity column gives me what I want but it is causing problems.

So I created this User_ID column that is an int identity column. The existing Id column in SpNetUsers table is not set as an identity column. The Id column is nvarchar(450) with Guids in it. So I should be able to create my own identity column shouldn't I? My understanding is that you can only have one identity column per table.

I can go through the registration screen and submit and it creates the record in the database. The record has the correctly incremented number in the User_ID column. I get sent the confirmation email with the link to click to confirm my email. But it then fails with this error when I click the link to load the ConfirmEmail page:
SqlException: Cannot update identity column 'User_ID'.

This is the line of code it fails on:

```
var result = await _userManager.ConfirmEmailAsync(user, code); 

Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand+<>c.<ExecuteDbDataReaderAsync>b__169_0(Task<SqlDataReader> result)
DbUpdateException: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.

Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.ReaderModificationCommandBatch.ExecuteAsync(IRelationalConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Cannot update identity column 'User_ID'.

   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.<>c.<ExecuteDbDataReaderAsync>b__169_0(Task`1 result)

   at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationResultTaskFromResultTask`2.InnerInvoke()

   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.<>c.<.cctor>b__277_0(Object obj)

   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)

--- End of stack trace from previous location ---

   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)

   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteWithThreadLocal(Task& currentTaskSlot, Thread threadPoolThread)

--- End of stack trace from previous location ---

   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.ReaderModificationCommandBatch.ExecuteAsync(IRelationalConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

ClientConnectionId:58b1dd83-c877-4fc0-9563-824f3aa5e418

Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.

 ---> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Cannot update identity column 'User_ID'.

   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.<>c.<ExecuteDbDataReaderAsync>b__169_0(Task`1 result)

   at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationResultTaskFromResultTask`2.InnerInvoke()

   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.<>c.<.cctor>b__277_0(Object obj)

   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)

--- End of stack trace from previous location ---

   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)

   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteWithThreadLocal(Task& currentTaskSlot, Thread threadPoolThread)

--- End of stack trace from previous location ---

   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.ReaderModificationCommandBatch.ExecuteAsync(IRelationalConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

ClientConnectionId:58b1dd83-c877-4fc0-9563-824f3aa5e418

Error Number:8102,State:1,Class:16

   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.ReaderModificationCommandBatch.ExecuteAsync(IRelationalConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.Internal.BatchExecutor.ExecuteAsync(IEnumerable`1 commandBatches, IRelationalConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.Internal.BatchExecutor.ExecuteAsync(IEnumerable`1 commandBatches, IRelationalConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.Internal.BatchExecutor.ExecuteAsync(IEnumerable`1 commandBatches, IRelationalConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChangesAsync(IList`1 entriesToSave, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChangesAsync(DbContext _, Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerExecutionStrategy.ExecuteAsync[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`4 operation, Func`4 verifySucceeded, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.SaveChangesAsync(Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.SaveChangesAsync(Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore.UserOnlyStore`6.UpdateAsync(TUser user, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1.UpdateUserAsync(TUser user)

   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1.ConfirmEmailAsync(TUser user, String token)

   at BeeKeeper.Areas.Identity.Pages.Account.ConfirmEmailModel.OnGetAsync(String userId, String code) in D:\mywork\BeeKeeper\Code\Areas\Identity\Pages\Account\ConfirmEmail.cshtml.cs:line 42

   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.ExecutorFactory.GenericTaskHandlerMethod.Convert[T](Object taskAsObject)

   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.ExecutorFactory.GenericTaskHandlerMethod.Execute(Object receiver, Object[] arguments)

   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.PageActionInvoker.InvokeHandlerMethodAsync()

   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.PageActionInvoker.InvokeNextPageFilterAsync()

   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.PageActionInvoker.Rethrow(PageHandlerExecutedContext context)

   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.PageActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)

   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.PageActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()

   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResourceFilter>g__Awaited|24_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)

   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContextSealed context)

   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)

   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>g__Awaited|19_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)

   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)

   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)

   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)

   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)

   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore.MigrationsEndPointMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)

   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

That error is in the scaffolded ConfirmEmail.shtml.cs file which has this code:
I haven't edited the code in that file apart from changing IdentityUser to ApplicationUser.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using BeeKeeper.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities;

namespace BeeKeeper.Areas.Identity.Pages.Account
{
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public class ConfirmEmailModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;

        public ConfirmEmailModel(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager)
        {
            _userManager = userManager;
        }

        [TempData]
        public string StatusMessage { get; set; }

        public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync(string userId, string code)
        {
            if (userId == null || code == null)
            {
                return RedirectToPage("/Index");
            }

            var user = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(userId);
            if (user == null)
            {
                return NotFound($"Unable to load user with ID '{userId}'.");
            }

            code = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(WebEncoders.Base64UrlDecode(code));
            var result = await _userManager.ConfirmEmailAsync(user, code);
            StatusMessage = result.Succeeded ? "Thank you for confirming your email." : "Error confirming your email.";
            return Page();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Provide your attempted code so we can easily understood your question.

Comment: My code is there at the top of the post. Not sure what other code you might want. The only code I added to get the User_ID column into the AspNetUsers table was that last two lines:
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
public int User_ID { get; set; }

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/identity/overview/extensibility/change-primary-key-for-users-in-aspnet-identity

Comment: I really can't understand your requirement, but according to Jeremy's comment, if you met error to change primary key?

Comment: I'm also getting this error when trying to reset the password of the user: Cannot update identity column 'User_ID'.

Comment: I didn't think that I should change the default Id column in the AspNetUsers. That's why I created the new User_ID column that would hold the integer that they label their bee hives with. But are you saying that it is ok to change the OOTB Id column from nvarchar(450) to an int column?

Comment: In my opinion, you now have a new column in the user table, so the issue happened on which kind action? You have trouble to update this table?

Comment: I am trying to follow that tutorial posted by Jeremy, but in my MVC Core application that I created recently, there is no IdentityModels.cs file. So I guess MVC Core does things differently to that tutorial so I'm not sure what to do. My application has \Areas\Identity\ for the scaffold identity pages. There is no Identity stuff added in the Models folder.

Comment: I think you may try to explain again about your concerns... Sorry for my stupid.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by creating a new UserProfile model so that all the extra data can get saved into a new UserProfile table instead of into the AspNetUssers table. On the Register.cshtml page I still have all the same form fields, but in the Register.cshtml.cs I now leave the Identity stuff as the default and save the extra fields into the new UserProfile table. CreatedById is the foreign key - AspNetUsers GUID of the person who created it:

```
var user = new IdentityUser { UserName = Input.Email, Email = Input.Email };

            var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, Input.Password);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                // try to create the UserProfile record now that the Uer has been created:
                using (var context = new ApplicationDbContext())
                {
                    var userProfile = new UserProfile
                    {
                        FirstName = Input.FirstName,
                        LastName = Input.LastName,
                        BusinessName = Input.BusinessName,
                        PostalAddress = Input.PostalAddress,
                        PostalPostcode = Input.PostalPostcode,
                        ResidentialAddress = Input.ResidentialAddress,
                        ResidentialPostcode = Input.ResidentialPostcode,
                        CreatedById = user.Id
                    };

                    context.UserProfile.Add(userProfile);
                    context.SaveChanges();
                }

                _logger.LogInformation("User created a new account with password.");

                var code = await _userManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user);
                code = WebEncoders.Base64UrlEncode(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(code));
                var callbackUrl = Url.Page(
                    "/Account/ConfirmEmail",
                    pageHandler: null,
                    values: new { area = "Identity", userId = user.Id, code = code, returnUrl = returnUrl },
                    protocol: Request.Scheme);

                await _emailSender.SendEmailAsync(Input.Email, "Confirm your email",
                    $"Please confirm your account by <a href='{HtmlEncoder.Default.Encode(callbackUrl)}'>clicking here</a>.");

                if (_userManager.Options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount)
                {
                    return RedirectToPage("RegisterConfirmation", new { email = Input.Email, returnUrl = returnUrl });
                }
                else
                {
                    await _signInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);
                    return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);
                }
            }
```